# Using the Button component of the native base in my react native project its produce issue in android text cut off

Tags: android, react-native, native-base

**IOS:**

[image]

**Android:**
[image]

In IOS it's working properly but android has issue As per the above image, I make component ButtonWithText.js its code given below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {Button} from 'native-base';

const ButtonWithText = props => {
  const content = (
    <Button transparent style={props.btnStyle} onPress={props.onButtonPress}>
      <Text style={props.textStyle}>{props.title}</Text>
    </Button>
  );
  return <View>{content}</View>;
};
export default ButtonWithText;
```

Currently, pass props from parent component given below:

```
<ButtonWithText
 title={'Want To Check Button Text'}
 btnStyle={styles.medicationButton}
 textStyle={styles.medicationButtonText}
 onButtonPress={() => goMedicationRefill(this.props.componentId)}
/>
```

Styles for above given below:

```
medicationButton: {
    height: 37,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#41FD9A',
    borderRadius: 18,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  medicationButtonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontWeight: '700',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
```

currently, I am using native-base version: 2.13.7 and react-native version: 0.60.5

Please help me out from this problem.